# How to automatically adjust furniture leg length

Tags: furniture, patio

My patio slabs were not laid perfectly true, so the garden furniture (uPVC table and chairs) wobbles. The usual fix for this is to slip folded paper or card under a leg – but I would like a more long-lasting solution.

I have seen plenty of products where the effective leg length is adjustable by screwing the foot further in or out. This is not what I am looking for, because it would need constantly adjusting as the furniture is moved.

Are there any (high or low-) tech solutions to this problem?

I am considering felt pads as a last resort. At least they may make the wobbling less harsh. Does anyone have any experience with this idea?

Comment: The only thing I can think of that would come close is a spring-loaded foot of some sort to do the "automatic" part with a twist or lever type lock that would hold it in place once the table/chair was leveled (similar to how legs lock on a tripod). However, I don't know if such a device is made. Unless the surface is _very_ uneven, I'd suggest a simple screw adjust and don't move the furniture that much. If it is that uneven, a better solution may be to level the surface - there is more than 1 question here about doing that.

Comment: Re-lay the patio slabs correctly...

Comment: Foam rubber feet would do a decent job I would think

Comment: Some washing machines have back feet that automatically level.  You set the front feet, tip the washer forward, and then when you let it down, the back feet set themselves.  Something to investigate. [Link to GE page about it](https://products.geappliances.com/appliance/gea-support-search-content?contentId=17817)

Comment: Also, three-legged tables don't wobble.  The feet are always coplanar.

Comment: Try restaurant supply store they have self leveling feet for restaurant tables.